# import data from Google fusion table into Google spreadsheet

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

I'm making a decent IT-inventory system using Google Drive. 
I wrote an Android app (using app inventor) that allows me to scan the barcode of a pc and add some comments to it. That data gets stored in a Google Fusion Table.

(Date | PC-code | Task)

Now I want to import the fusion table into a Google Spreadsheet. That way, I can create a list and see what computers I have seen/installed software on and what computers I still have to see.

I have tried using

```
 =importxml()
 =importurl()
 =importrange()
```

But as I'm not at all good in mysql-queries and as I can't seem to find a decent solution on the net, I figured asking here...

Thanks in advance!

PS:

[Here is the sample fusion table I use in my android app.](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1O6BvKGENHw8XEx9aEk8Q8qtBO9CYxfURPWNzXwbM#rows:id=1)

[Here is a sample (empty) spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i4d4IUIaDCEbAsq-RB0n1sAxShlMcqqgrTl6xpW1u9Q/edit?usp=sharing)

An answer to this problem would be very helpfull and save me a lot of "typing" time.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126412/import-private-google-fusion-table-to-google-docs-spreadsheet

Comment: It is very usefull, but I was hoping to be able to do this without Apps Script, as I'd like to be able to use it on my iPad/android device. Thanks a lot anyway, I'll see if I can figure out how they do it in the link you provided.

Comment: The documentation states that `=importrange()` gets data from another spreadsheet.  So that's eliminated.  There is no `=importurl()` function.  There is a `=importData(url)` function.  For that, the url must be in csv or tsv format, and I don't think the fusion table file is in that format.

Comment: If you can make an HTTP GET request from your device, you can call the Apps Script file and get it to run I think.  It would need to be a Stand Alone app that uses Content Service.

Comment: Yes, exactly. After a long search, I came to the same conclusions, but I wasn't 100% sure about the `=importxml()` function. I'v seen some crazy spreadsheets using that function... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable the Advanced Google Service for Fusion Tables:

[Google Documentation - Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables)

In the Apps Script code editor, choose **RESOURCES**, **ADVANCED GOOGLE SERVICES**.

You will get a pop up window that looks like this:

[image]

Turn Fusion Tables ON, and then click the link at the bottom of the window to go to your Developers Console

[image: DevelopersConsole]

Scroll to Fusion Tables, and click OFF to turn it ON.  The item will be removed from the list and go to the top of the page:

[image: Enabled APIs]

Take a look at the sample code here:

[Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables)

I copied the sample code, and changed it a bit.  I tested it, and it puts all my Fusion table data into the current spreadsheet and the active sheet.

```
function runQuery(tableId) {
  tableId = "yourTableID";

  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableId + ' LIMIT 100';
  var result = FusionTables.Query.sqlGet(sql, {
    hdrs: false
  });
  if (result.rows) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Append the headers.
    sheet.appendRow(result.columns);

    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, result.rows.length, result.columns.length)
        .setValues(result.rows);

    Logger.log('Query results spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } else {
    Logger.log('No rows returned.');
  }
}
```

Open up the fusion table that you want to get data from, and get the file ID out of the URL:

```
google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1LDLJFU398UFOjB4-BS89IOHV89TYHTOHC&pli=1#rows:id=1
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need. :-D Have a great weekend!